# Is the relative url in the source of a webpage supposed to be appended to the url of the webpage?

Tags: html

I am checking the source of a webpage whose url is

```
http://localhost:12345/web/query?name=time&
```

In the source of the html webpage, I saw a relative url:

```
<a href="./query?name=time&params=3">Date</a>
```

Is the relative url in the source supposed to be appended to the url of the webpage? In the above example, is it

```
http://localhost:12345/web/query?name=time&./query?name=time&params=3
```

Or is how to interpret the relative url in the webpage completely up to the author of the webpage?

When a web browser renders the webpage, the web browser interprets the relative url as

```
http://localhost:12345/web/query?name=time&params=3
```

I wonder how the browser can guess how the author interprets it.

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't reproduce what you're saying in Chrome. I also rarely if ever see `href="./`

Answer (score 1):

./ is relative to the directory the file is in. I'd never use paths like that personally.

If the file is /web/query then `<a href="./query?name=time">Date</a>` and `<a href="query?name=time">Date</a>` would essentially be the same thing. Obviously that link has to be found at the first level inside the /web directory or it wouldn't point to the right place, which is why I never use those type of paths, I always use paths that start at the document root, /.

These types of paths are usually found when developers either can't or don't know how to set up a proper web server for the site in my experience.